# How to pass values of a column of rows whose checkboxes are selected in jQuery Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have a datatable which is getting populated by an ajax call. Following is the code:

```
oTable = $('#lenderList').dataTable(
        {
            bServerSide: true,
            bProcessing: true,
            searching: true,
            sAjaxSource: "loanAdminAjax?ajax=true&searchCol="+$('#category').val(),
            sServerMethod: 'POST',
            sPaginationType: "full_numbers",

            columnDefs:[
                {
                    targets:8,
                    checkboxes:{
                        selectrow:true
                    }
                }
            ],
            aoColumns: [
                {
                    "sName": "loanApplicationNumber",
                    mData: "loanApplicationNumber"
                },
                {
                    "sName": "name",
                    mData: "name"
                },
                {
                    "sName": "submissionDate",
                    mData: "submissionDate"
                },
                {
                    "sName": "kycEmailId",
                    mData: "kycEmailId"
                },
                {
                    "sName": "appVersion",
                    mData: "appVersion"
                },
                {
                    "sName": "documentStatus",
                    mData: "documentStatus"
                },
                {
                    "sName": "latestRemark",
                    mData: "latestRemark"
                },
                {
                    "sName": "appName",
                    mData: "appName"
                },
                {
                    nData:   "salaryTransaction",
                    render: function ( salaryTransaction, type, row ) {
                        if ( type === 'display' ) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                        }
                        return salaryTransaction;
                    },
                    className: "dt-body-center"
                }
            ],
            dom: '<"button">lfrtip'
        }
    );
});
```

I have to consider all the loan application numbers of the respective rows whose checkboxes are checked by the user. So I can trigger an event on Click of a button but how can I get the values of Loan Application Number of those rows whose checkboxes are clicked.

I am new to javaScript. Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this idea : Loop through all the `rows` of the `table`, and test if the `checkbox` of that `row` is `checked` or not. If it is, then extract the `value` of the needed cell!

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      oTable = $("#lenderList").dataTable(); // Get the datatable,
      var loanApplicationNumbers = []; // An array that will contain the "loan application numbers"
      oTable.$('tr').each(function(index,rowhtml){ //Loop through the table rows
        //Check the state of the checkbox
        var checked= $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked',rowhtml).length;
        if (checked==1){
          //If the checkbox is checked, then add the inner text of the cell to the array
          loanApplicationNumbers.push(rowhtml.children[1].innerText);
        }
      });
      console.log(loanApplicationNumbers); //Do whatever you want
    });
});
```

**Note :** `rowhtml.children` is an `Array` of cells in that row, if you want to get the value of the first cell, you should do `rowhtml.children[0].innerText` .